# Comparing the predicted class for each instance of test data from different models

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, classification, supervised-learning

My test set data contains about 50,000 instances. I trained different machine learning models. Now I want to do some comparison to see for example if for every instance `x_i` that model A predicted as 0, models B and C also predicted that instance as 0.

For example, below are the first 5 predictions by the models.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'true_class': [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0],
 'rf_pred': [3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 'mlp_pred': [3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 'knn_pred': [3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 'lg_pred': [3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 'ada_pred': [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
 true_class rf_pred mlp_pred knn_pred lg_pred ada_pred
0   3.0     3.0     3.0      3.0      3.0      2.0
1   3.0     0.0     0.0      0.0      0.0      2.0
2   3.0     0.0     0.0      0.0      0.0      2.0
3   3.0     0.0     0.0      0.0      0.0      2.0
4   3.0     0.0     0.0      0.0      0.0      2.0
```

Clearly predictions of `rf_pred, mlp_pred, knn_pred` & `lg_pred` are the same for these five instances.

Is there any way to perform such analysis, per haps visually?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a heatmap approach:
Each row shows a model's predictions, each column is an instance predicted and the color represents the value predicted.

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.imshow(list(data.values()), y = list(data.keys()))
fig.show()
```

[image: Heatmap showing predictions from 5 models]

Secondly you could compare models with each other, by comparing the rates at which they predict the same category for the same instance.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
rate_of_same_prediction = df.apply(lambda x:[ (x== df[ col ]).mean() for col in df.columns], axis=0)
rate_of_same_prediction.index = rate_of_same_prediction.columns 
fig = px.imshow(rate_of_same_prediction)
fig.show()
```

Here both columns and rows represent your models.

[image]

Comment: May I know why you consider taking columns' mean in `x== df[ col ]).mean()`?

Comment: Yes, x== df[ col ]) gives a series of True/False, indicating whether the two models being compared (columns) predicted the same category for the same instance. The mean of this is the rate a which they predict the same. '1' is the same in all instances and '0' is never the same. (True/False I interpreted as 1/0 when calculating the mean).

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# To check the relationship between those predictions
plt.scatter(df[true_class], df[rf_pred])
```

You can as well use the `df.corr()` method or use the `regplot` method in seaborn

Comment: `regplot` method? Can you add details to your answer?

Comment: import seaborn as sns --> sns.regplot(x=df['true_class'], y=df['rf_pred']);................you do the same to other columns as well ...

Comment: But this means line regression plot not categorical.